# When I edit contacts on my Nexus S, it's deleting their birthdays from Google Contacts. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: contacts, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s

Is it something I'm doing wrong?

Where do  I report this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing there isn't a field for Birthday in the Android contacts app, and when you edit it's replacing the old info with the info on your phone (which has no birthday due to no field for it).

Here's the process for reporting bugs at Android.com: http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html